# How to make google index press releases or new items as they are released

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search, google-index

I have noticed that several website news items are indexed immediately by Google. Even questions posted on stackexchange.com are indexed by Google within minutes. Can someone tell me how i can do that with the website which has frequent news items on website.

How can i achieve this with otherwise with has frequent news or press releases posted.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of questions and answers on Pro Webmasters already regarding the speeding up of indexing and crawl rates.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your site to be indexed as quickly as Stack Exchange sites then you need a site that is equally as good and equally as visited i.e millions of visitors each month.

*Google crawler has limited resources*

Google has limited resources and reserves a lot of the resources for 'TOP Sites' i.e those that often have regular content being posted every couple of mins and is regularly visited and linked too in the millions. [Stack Overflow for example is within the TOP 60](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com) in the world for most visited websites, if you want special treatment then you need a special site

*Increasing your crawl time and rate*

You need to gain more authority that can be broken down as:

- Age (Older is better than new if the site is popular and remains popular)
- Freshness (The rate you update your content)
- Regular Content (Adding content on a regular basis)
- Social mentions (Social mentions can trigger quick page updates)
- Backlinks (Gains authority, improves rankings and can trigger quicker updates)

Ultimately unless you have a top 250 world site your not going to achieve indexes as quickly as Stack Exchange....

Comment: I had a site that years ago that enjoyed getting pages spidered, indexed, and search traffic within 20 minutes from posting a new page. It was not the topic of the site actually, just a small very topic. It does not have to such a valuable site or a big site, but freshness and uniqueness counts! In my case, I was posting somewhat contrarian views of HR matters based upon solid research and the experience of many. Because it was not the same 'ol same 'ol it was watched carefully and linked to. This is the power of having a voice when you find your niche.

Comment: There's a lot of difference between 20mins and often under 30secs to 1min on Stack Exchange ;)

Comment: But I am not SE. If I could do it on my nothing site, then anyone can. That was my point. Just offering a bit of hope- pathetic as it may be! ;-)